# Is there any method available to find changed attributes for objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to fetch only changed attributes of an object. Is there any method available which returns all the updated attributes?

Comment: -1 For confusing Ruby and Rails, or at least, not being clear enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given there aren't many specifics in your question, I'm going to assume you're referring to ActiveRecord objects. To view the changed attributes on so called "Dirty Objects" you can do the following:

```
User.changed #=> ["name", "email"]

User.changes #=> { "name" => ["Joe", "Joseph"] }
```

There are also methods for each attribute if you need to check specific ones.

```
User.name_changed? #=> true

User.name_change #=> ["Joe", "Joseph"]
```

More details here:
http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects

Comment: (rdb:118) self.misc1_id_changed?
true (rdb:118) self.misc1_id_change
[5, 5].. Why it's appearing as changed there are no changes in values..

Comment: If the values are the same, the attribute shouldn't be flagged as changed. What modifications are you making to the object prior to checking what has changed?

Comment: On update i am passing values from my form. I am modifing only one attributes. However, i am getting all the attributes values has changed true.
I want to set condition on update. User can only modify some of the attributes. If user will update other attributes than i want to return errors.
But getting all the attributes as changed if attributes are not changed. And it's showing the same values.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why that is happening, can you update your question with the relevant code?

Comment: I am using Flex as my front end. May be that's causing problem in between some where aroung passing objects from rails to flex and flex to rails..

Answer (score 0):

Yes ActiveRecord:Dirty, however you can't see changes to objects saved to the Db, such as user.save :(

Comment: You can achieve that with something like papertrail https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail